# Maven build deploy target throwing exception for Sonatype Nexus Repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I am using the following snippet in my pom to deploy the artifact. It was working till now and started failing recently.

The same build file is working fine when I kick off the build from Jenkins Linux box.

```
<profile>
    <id>snapshots-repository</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>!useReleaseRepo</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>nexus</name>
            <url>https://${nexus.instance}.xxx.com:8443/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>prod-release-repository</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>useReleaseRepo</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>nexus</name>
            <url>https://${nexus.instance}.xxx.com:8443/repository/maven-releases/ </url>           
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</profile>
```

Error:

> Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access https://nexus.com:8443/repository/maven-snapshots/ with 
>   type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access https://nexus.com:8443/repository/maven-snapshots/ using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException

I'm looking for a recommendation for what needs to be changed to make it work again. I didn't change my .m2/settings file also.

Comment: Appears your edit moved blocks of text into code blocks. Good practice to keep text out of code blocks to make the post more readable.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -X ...` for debug infos? And, this shouldn't really matter, but I'd remove the trailing blank in the release `<url>`.